# Detecting already inserted data mysql on unique index

Tags: php, mysql

How can I detect if inserted data already exists?

So far I have a unique index on the table `email`

```
function insertEmail($email)
{
    mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO `emails` (email, sent) VALUES ('$email', DATE( '0000-00-00' ))");
}

    if (insertEmail($emails)) {
        echo "<span class='success'>Successfully added " . $emails . " to the queue</span><br/>";
    } else {
        echo "<span class='fail'>Error we already sent " . $emails . " an invitation email.</span><br/>";
    }
```

Even if the data doesn't exist in `emails` it still returns:

`Error we already sent example@gmail.com an invitation email.`  `Successfully added...` is never achieved.

How can I detect if it exists or not?

Comment: Your `insertEmail` function always returns `null`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `insertEmail` to something like

```
function insertEmail($email)
{
    mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO `emails` (email, sent) VALUES ('$email', DATE( '0000-00-00' ))");
    return mysql_affected_rows() > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason you're getting the error is because you're not actually returning anything from your function, so insertEmail is never going to return as true.  Try adding a catch for that and see if you still receive the same result like:

```
function insertEmail($email)
{
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO `emails` (email, sent) VALUES ('$email', DATE( '0000-00-00' ))");
    $rows = mysql_affected_rows();
    return $rows
}
```

Comment: `mysql_affected_rows()` accepts a connection handler, not a result handler.